# How to update a table without accessing the web in Laravel (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, web

I am trying to create a web application using Laravel to manage quizzes. The quizzes are timed. I have made a javascript countdown timer, and it counts down until the deadline. If the student is taking the quiz and the deadline has reached, I can redirect the student to the home page with a message e.g. 'Time is up!' and update the table, so it shows that the quiz is completed (since it reached the deadline).

I am wondering how to make the application updates the table even when the student is not on the quiz page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the quiz is **started**, use Laravel to update your database and enter the deadline date/time.

The JavaScript time out is useful from a user experience perspective, but can easily be altered or bypassed entirely. By adding the deadline time to your database, you can do validation and logic checks before and after the deadline has passed, such as:

- Check if the submission occurred after the deadline has passed, regardless of the JS timeout
- If the user is forced to reload the page for whatever reason, you can update the timer appropriately